# What is the rationale behind pytest.approx's rel parameter?

Tags: pytest

The documentation of `pytest.approx` mentions `rel` parameter but it does not **define** it clearly.

This returns `True` as expected,

```
>>> a = 1e-6
>>> b = 2e-6
>>> a == approx(b, abs=1e-6) # returns True
```

However this returns `False`

```
>>> a = 1e-6
>>> b = 2e-6
>>> a == approx(b, rel=1e-6) # returns False
```

Why is there a `rel` parameter here? What's its use-case?

Does it multiply `b` with `rel` and considers that as the tolerance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, this is what it does. It is mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest-approx) that it is relative to b, and as it is a relative tolerance, multiplication with the value is implied.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for this can be unclear and assumes you already know what a relative tolerance is. Essentially, a relative tolerance allows you to compare two quantities on the same scale, regardless of whether they are small or large. The formula for this is `|value - expected_value| / |expected_value|`, and you can learn more about it on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error):

#### TLDR - Simple Answer

```
a == approx(b, rel) <-> |b - a| / |b|  <= rel
```

The expression on the left is equivalent to the one on the right.

#### Dealing with 0s

However, there is a complication: if b is equal to 0, you can't divide by 0, which causes issues. To account for this, the developers added another complexity, resulting in the following expression:

Now, there if you only pass an`abs` parameter (ommiting `rel`) the actual comparison is the following:

```
a == approx(b, rel, abs) <-> |b - a|  <= max(|rel * b|, abs)
```

Note that if `b=0` then `abs` is used to assert the difference.

#### Special case

Finally, there is an special case when you pass only the absolute difference when the expression is the following:

```
a == approx(b, rel, abs) <-> |b - a|  <= abs
```

[the documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest-approx) actually covers this but it is hard to find. Hopefully this clarifies the use for you.